# Equating patterns on a grid

Tags: java, algorithm, pattern-matching

Say I have a grid set out as the four shown [here](https://dumpyourphoto.com/photo/QBMpSf80NC) and want to determine that these are the same, but simply rotations of each other. How might I go about this?
I can check opposite image by simply turning the grid into a binary string and reversing it but I am stuck on how I might check the 90 degree rotations of this.

Comment: turn it into 2D array and exchange rows by columns,

Comment: why not directly compare the grid entries? how is your grid represented?

Answer (score 0):

What pola said. Example for 90 deg (for other cases, compare to `grid2[size-y-1][x]` etc):

```
boolean matchesRot90(int[][] grid1, int[][] grid2) {
  int size = grid1.length; 
  for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
      if (grid1[x][y] != grid2[y][x]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```